# Fourier series to a function

Tags: fourier-series

Assume that $f(x)$ is periodically extended outside the original interval.
Find the Fourier series of the extended function.
$f(x)=2(1-x^2), -1\leq x<1$
So I find that $a_0 =\frac{4}{3}$ and to find $a_n$ I need to compute this:
$$\int_{-1}^{1} 2 (1-x^2) \cos(n \pi x) dx$$
which is 
$$\frac{8 \sin(\pi n)-8 \pi n \cos(\pi n)}{\pi^3 n^3}$$
or simply 
$$\frac{-8\cos(\pi n)}{\pi^2 n^2}$$
Now I have two misunderstandings:

1. Looking at the answer to this exercise:
   $$f(x)=\frac{4}{3}+\frac{8}{\pi^2} \Sigma _{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \cos(n \pi x)}{n^2}$$
   I conclude that I did wrong with my $a_n$ calculation.
2. Where is the minus sign to my $a_n$?

Answer (score 2):

The minus sign is absorbed by $(-1)^{n+1}$: you have your original $-1$, and then $\cos(\pi n) = (-1)^n$, so $a_n = \dfrac{8 (-1)^{n+1}}{\pi^2 n^2}$, and the constant (not depending on $n$) parts of the term are brought out front of the sum.

Comment: Thank you. I got this thing right after I wrote my question...